# Phone stuck in fastboot mode

Tags: rooting, twrp, magisk, hosts, oneplus-6

I've rooted my OnePlus 6 yesterday. To do so, I followed this guide:

[Root Your OnePlus 6 with Magisk — A Beginner's Guide](https://oneplus.gadgethacks.com/how-to/root-your-oneplus-6-with-magisk-beginners-guide-0185541/)

```
TWRP version: 3.5.1_9-0
Magisk version: 22.0
```

I also installed the Magisk app on my phone

Now  I've edited my hosts-file (needed to change some permissions to be able to modify this file
) to block some sites. I've restarted the phone once successfully, but now the phone will not boot anymore. When I power on, I see the OnePlus logo very briefly and then it gets stuck on the "bootloader is unlocked" warning for a long time. It then goes on into fastboot mode. If i press start from there, the process repeats. If I press recovery mode I still get into TWRP, but rebooting from there also repeats the process and does not boot up my phone successfully.

I'm not sure, but I don't think editing the hosts file is what caused this? Shouldn't I be able to edit this file without bricking my device?

Any help on what happened and how I can fix this bootloop without wiping/reinstalling my entire device would be greatly appreciated; I don't want to lose all my settings =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I edited the system hosts file. This causes the system to be unable to boot; the reason is `dm-verity` which denies boot (chain of trust) when any modified system file is detected.

To fix the issue, I followed https://www.droidwin.com/restore-oneplus-6-stock-via-fastboot-commands/

Basically, it explains how to download the stock ROM, extract the `.bin` file into multiple `.img` files, and how to flash them subsequently.

Since only the `boot` and `system` partitions were modified, and I did not want to lose my data, I flashed them using

```
fastboot flash boot_a boot.img 
fastboot flash boot_b boot.img 
fastboot flash system_a system.img 
fastboot flash system_b system.img
```

This fixed the issue =).